# How to implement this particular class hierarchy?

Tags: c#, oop

I have series of classes that are implementing `CompareTo` method from `IComparable` interface.

```
    public int CompareTo(CMNewsletter obj)
    {
        CMNewsletter c = obj;
        return String.Compare(c.Name, this.Name);
    }
```

Each class has it's own `CompareTo` implementation. So the implementation should be done in each class.

Now there is a need to call CompareTo on some base class objects. `CMBase` is a base class class for all before mentioned classes.

The following code is how I want to design my classes.

```
CMBase reference, copy;
if (reference.CompareTo(copy) == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not changed");
}
```

`reference` and `copy` objects will be of type `CMNewsletter` or other, where the actual implementation of `CompareTo` is residing.

I'm not sure how to implement whole class hierarchy to accomplish what I described.

Comment: do you really want to compare some `CMNewsletter` to another derived object? Isn't it enough to compare the base-fields (well it *should* be!) - if you want to keep the classes open you cannot do this in a reasonable way

Comment: If you always call CompareTo and check against zero like this `CompareTo() == 0`, you probably implemented wrong interface, you need to implement `IEquatable` then.

Comment: seeing as your WriteLine output is "Not changed", it seems you are trying to see if the object is the same, which is not what `IComparable` is for.  `IEquatable` would tell you that 5 is not equal to 7. `IComparable` would tell you that 5 comes before 7.

Comment: @Carsten König: yes I want to compare `CMNewsletter` to another `CMNewsletter` instance using some base class objects as `reference` and `copy`. But this can be other class also like `CMEvent` and I don't want the code dealing with `reference`/`copy` comparison know about each child class. I think what I want is polymorphism?

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel, @Andrew Counts: I will substitude `IComperable` to `IEquatable`, but the question remains same.

Comment: How would you compare a newsletter and an event? Are those even logically comparable? How would you determine that a given newsletter is less than a given event?

Comment: @usr: I don't need to compare newsletter to an event. It's always same child objects. newsletter to newsletter, event to event.

Comment: So why not just go with a simple abstract CompareTo method like you seem to have it already? What's wrong about that? See the answer that has already arrived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off you need to Implement `IEquatable` and not `IComparable`. Then you introduce two helper method namely `EqualsHelper` and `EqualsCore` to get the job done.

`EqualsHelper` is just a helper method to find if equality fails and `EqualsCore` is virtual, which you need to override in all derived classes and implement its equality there, nothing else.

```
class MyBase : IEquatable<MyBase>
{
    public bool Equals(MyBase other)
    {
        return EqualsHelper(other);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return EqualsHelper(obj as MyBase);
    }

    protected bool EqualsHelper(MyBase other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        if (other.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return EqualsCore(other);
    }

    protected virtual bool EqualsCore(MyBase other)
    {
        return BaseProperty == other.BaseProperty;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return BaseProperty;
    }

    public int BaseProperty { get; set; }
}

class Derived : MyBase, IEquatable<Derived>
{
    public int DerivedProperty { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Derived other)
    {
        return EqualsHelper(other);
    }

    protected override bool EqualsCore(MyBase other)
    {
        Derived obj = (Derived)other;
        return base.EqualsCore(obj) &&
            this.DerivedProperty == obj.DerivedProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way I also tried to go but it seemed to me weird - when child `Equals` is called, it's calling parent's helper and that helper is calling child's `EqualsCore`. No way to avoid this jump? Although this looks like addressing the issue, in other words is this the best approach?

Comment: @Pablo That's what we call it as polymorphism or late binding, anyhow you need to override `Equals(object obj)` in all the types, so for me this looks good approach. Give it a try if no other better answers :)

Answer (score -1):

I would make CMBase abstract class implementing IComparable interface as abstract method:

```
public abstract class CMBase : IComparable
{
    public abstract int CompareTo(object o);
}
```

This will make all derived classes implement the CompareTo method. If you can't make this class abstract, then you can make implementation virtual which just throws exception, or if acceptable - implement some default comparison logic.

Comment: `CMBase is abstract but it is contained in non-abstract class`

Comment: @Pablo so what? Can't it implement IComparable then?

Comment: @Pablo, First of all, you didn't specify in the question, that your class is contained inside other class, so I don't understand why you think I should know that. Second, if abstract class is contained inside non-abstract class - that doesn't prevent it from implementing an interface like IComparable. I double-clecked that and it compiles successfully. Or is there something else you didn't specify and I should have guessed?